# Error uploading image through cloudinary api in nextjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js, cloudinary

I have this page used to create a post. It was initially created to upload multiple images, but after changing some things so that it will accept a single image, the code seems to break during submission but it works fine when selecting the image.

When I click to submit, I get the error message `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) client.js:26 Error uploading image: AxiosError` from the cloudinary api in the console.

Below are the corresponding codes
**Create post page**

```
import styles from "@/styles/products.module.scss";
import Layout from "@/components/admin/layout";
import db from "@/utils/db";
import Category from "@/models/Category";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import axios from "axios";
import * as Yup from "yup";
import { Form, Formik } from "formik";
import SingularSelect from "@/components/selects/SingularSelect";
import AdminInput from "@/components/inputs/adminInput";
import DialogModal from "@/components/dialogModal";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import Images from "@/components/admin/createProduct/images";
import { uploadImages } from "@/requests/upload";
import DotLoader from "@/components/loaders/dotLoader";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import News from "@/models/News";

const initialState = {
  name: "",
  description: "",
  post: "",
  image: "",
  parent: "",
  category: "",
  subCategories: [],
};

export default function create({ parents, categories }) {
  const [product, setProduct] = useState(initialState);
  const [subs, setSubs] = useState([]);
  const [image, setImage] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getParentData = async () => {
      if (product.parent) {
        try {
          const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/product/${product.parent}`);
          if (data) {
            setProduct({
              ...product,
              name: data.name,
              description: data.description,
              category: data.category,
              subCategories: data.subCategories,
            });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching parent data:", error);
        }
      }
    };

    getParentData();
  }, [product.parent]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { value, name } = e.target;
    setProduct({ ...product, [name]: value });
  };

  const validate = Yup.object({
    name: Yup.string()
      .required("Please add a name")
      .min(10, "Product name must bewteen 10 and 300 characters.")
      .max(300, "Product name must bewteen 10 and 300 characters."),
    category: Yup.string().required("Please select a category."),
    description: Yup.string().required("Please add a description"),
  });

  const createProductHandler = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      let uploaded_image = "";

      if (image) {
        const path = "product images";
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("path", path);
        formData.append("file", image);
        const response = await uploadImages(formData);
        console.log(response);
        uploaded_image = response;
      }
      setLoading(false);
      console.log("successful", data);
      toast.success(data.message);
router.push("/admin/dashboard/product/all");
      router.push("/admin/dashboard/product/all");
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false);
      toast.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Layout>
        {loading && <DotLoader loading={loading} />}
        <div className={styles.header}>Create Product</div>
        <DialogModal />
        <Formik
          enableReinitialize
          initialValues={{
            name: product.name,
            post: product.post,
            description: product.description,
            category: product.category,
            subCategories: product.subCategories,
            parent: product.parent,
            imageInputFile: "",
          }}
          validationSchema={validate}
          onSubmit={() => {
            createProductHandler();
          }}
        >
          {(formik) => (
            <Form>
              <Images
                name="imageInputFile"
                header="Post Image"
                text="Add images"
                image={image}
                setImage={setImage}
              />
              <AdminInput
                type="text"
                label="Name"
                name="name"
                placholder="Post name"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <AdminInput
                type="text"
                label="Post"
                name="post"
                placholder="Post story"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <SingularSelect
                name="category"
                value={product.category}
                placeholder="Category"
                data={categories}
                header="Select a Category"
                handleChange={handleChange}
                disabled={product.parent}
              />
              <div className={styles.header}>Basic Infos</div>

              <AdminInput
                type="text"
                label="Description"
                name="description"
                placholder="Post description"
                onChange={handleChange}
              />

              <button
                className={`${styles.btn} ${styles.btn__primary} ${styles.submit_btn}`}
                type="submit"
              >
                Create Product
              </button>
            </Form>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </Layout>
    </>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps(ctx) {
  await db.connectDb();
  const results = await News.find().select("name").lean();
  const categories = await Category.find().lean();
  // db.disconnectDb();
  return {
    props: {
      parents: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)),
      categories: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categories)),
    },
  };
}
```

**Selecting Images page**

```
import { ErrorMessage, useField } from "formik";
import { useRef } from "react";
import { FaStaylinked } from "react-icons/fa";
import { RiDeleteBin7Fill, RiShape2Line } from "react-icons/ri";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { showDialog } from "@/store/DialogSlice";
import styles from "./styles.module.scss";
import { GiExtractionOrb } from "react-icons/gi";
export default function Images({
  image,
  setImage,
  header,
  text,
  name,
  setColorImage,
  ...props
}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const fileInput = useRef(null);
  const [meta, field] = useField(props);

  const handleImages = (e) => {
    const file = e.target.files[0]; // Get the first selected file from the input
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.readAsDataURL(file); // Read the file as a data URL
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      setImage(e.target.result); // Update the state with the image data URL
    };
  };
  // const handleRemove = (image) => {
  //   setImage((image) => image.filter((item) => item !== image));
  // };

  const handleRemove = () => {
    setImage(""); // Set the image state to an empty string
  };
  return (
    <div className={styles.images}>
      <div
        className={`${styles.header} ${meta.error ? styles.header__error : ""}`}
      >
        <div className={styles.flex}>
          {meta.error && <img src="../../../images/warning.png" alt="" />}
          {header}
        </div>
        <span>
          {meta.touched && meta.error && (
            <div className={styles.error__msg}>
              <span></span>
              <ErrorMessage name={name} />
            </div>
          )}
        </span>
      </div>
      <input
        type="file"
        name={name}
        ref={fileInput}
        hidden
        // multiple
        accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/webp"
        onChange={handleImages}
        // {...field}
      />
      <div className={styles.images__main}>
        <div className={`${styles.images__main_grid}`}>
          {!image?.length ? (
            <img src="../../../images/no_image.png" alt="" />
          ) : (
            <div className={styles.images__main_grid_wrap}>
              <div className={styles.blur}></div>
              <img src={image} alt="" />
              <div className={styles.images__main_grid_actions}>
                <button onClick={() => handleRemove(image)}>
                  <RiDeleteBin7Fill />
                </button>
                <button>
                  <RiShape2Line />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      <button
        type="reset"
        style={{ opacity: `${image?.length >= 1 && "0.5"}` }}
        onClick={() => fileInput.current.click()}
        className={`${styles.btn} ${styles.btn__primary}`}
        // disabled={image?.length >= 1}
      >
        {text}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Upload to cloudinary page**

```
import axios from "axios";

export const uploadImages = async (formData) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.post("/api/cloudinary", formData, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      },
    });
    console.log(response);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error uploading image:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to upload image to Cloudinary.");
  }
};
```

**Post Cloudinary api route page**

```
import { createRouter } from "next-connect";
import cloudinary from "cloudinary";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import fs from "fs";
import fileUpload from "express-fileupload";
import { imgMiddleware } from "../../../middleware/imgMiddleware";

cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: process.env.CLOUDINARY_NAME,
  api_key: process.env.CLOUDINARY_KEY,
  api_secret: process.env.CLOUDINARY_SECRET,
});
const router = createRouter()
  .use(
    fileUpload({
      useTempFiles: true,
      tempFileDir: "/tmp/",
    })
  )
  .use(imgMiddleware);
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};
router.post(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { path } = req.body || {};
    // let files = Object.values(req.files).flat();
    let file = req.file;
    console.log(file);
    // let image = "";
    // for (const file of files) {
    const img = await uploadToCloudinaryHandler(file, path);
    // image.push(img);
    removeTmp(file.tempFilePath);
    // }
    res.json(img);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

router.delete(async (req, res) => {
  let image_id = req.body.public_id;
  cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(image_id, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return res.status(400).json({ success: false, err });
    res.json({ success: true });
  });
});

const uploadToCloudinaryHandler = async (file, path) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(
      file.tempFilePath,
      {
        folder: path,
      },
      (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          removeTmp(file.tempFilePath);
          console.log(err);
          return res.status(400).json({ message: "Upload image failed." });
        }
        resolve({
          url: res.secure_url,
          public_url: res.public_id,
        });
      }
    );
  });
};
const removeTmp = (path) => {
  fs.unlink(path, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
};

export default router.handler();
```

**and finally, The post route handler page api**

```
import { createRouter } from "next-connect";
import db from "@/utils/db";
import Product from "@/models/News";
import auth from "@/middleware/auth";
import admin from "@/middleware/admin";
import slugify from "slugify";
const router = createRouter().use(auth).use(admin);

router.post(async (req, res) => {
  try {
    db.connectDb();
    req.body.slug = slugify(req.body.name);
    const newProduct = new Product({
      name: req.body.name,
      description: req.body.description,
      brand: req.body.brand,
      slug: slugify(req.body.name),
      category: req.body.category,
      subCategories: req.body.subCategories,
    });
    await newProduct.save();
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Post created Successfully." });
    db.disconnectDb();
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});
```

Comment: could you please check the logs on your server after you upload an image and get an HTTP 400 error to see if an exception is thrown in your server logs?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, in the cloudinary page, I still had to accept the image by restructuring it to receive a file i.e `const file = req.files.file` instead of the previouse `req.file`